# How to add a border to an image?

Tags: c#, wpf

Why can't I add a border to the image I've added? What's wrong with this code?

```
<Border Name="imgBorder" BorderThickness="2">
    <Image Height="150" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Margin="90,239,0,0" Name="image1" 
     Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     Width="200" 
     Source="/ControlsBasics-WPF;component/GalleryImages/Lighthouse.jpg" 
     ImageFailed="image1_ImageFailed" />

</Border>
```

Answer (score 5):

The default value for your Border's color, aka `BorderBrush`, is null, which means you won't see a border unless you specify its color. 
Also, you specify a crazy high value for the Image's Margin, which will draw your `Image` 90 pixels right and 239 under the actual border!
Example for a black border

```
<Border Name="imgBorder" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Source="/ControlsBasics-WPF;component/GalleryImages/Lighthouse.jpg" ImageFailed="image1_ImageFailed" />

        </Border>
```

Comment: unfortunately the border does not apply to the image, but to a different area. look at the link  http://i57.tinypic.com/k3rqqp.png

Comment: Can't see the image (stupid work firewall) but I just realized your `Margin` being incredibly high. The border will be drawn 90 pixels left, 239 pixels above your image. Try setting the Image's Margin to 0